# Colspan appearing as 'unknown' attribute

Tags: html, angular, sass

I am trying to build the following HTML table with 3 header columns in `<thead>` and 5 rows in `<tbody>` with the 5 rows spanning the full length of the header.

```
 <table>
      <thead>
        <th class="col-4">
          Placeholder
        </th>
        <th class="col-5">
          Placeholder
        </th>
        <th>
          <button>
            <em class="fa fa-trash-alt"></em>
          </button>
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Description: </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Opportunities: </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Risks: </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Dependencies: </strong></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I thought of doing it using the colspan attribute of my `<td>` element, however my IDE underlines the attribute in the SCSS file saying it is unknown attribute.

Comment: One question: Why you are using colspan in SCSS? It can be used in html file only I guess.

Comment: You’re trying to set colspan via scss? Set it via html template `<td [attr.colspan]=“someValue”…` or `<td colspan=“3”…`

Comment: It's an Angular application.

Comment: @liberlux doesn’t matter that it’s an angular app, usual scss and html rules apply

Comment: @liberlux share the scss file part also!

Comment: No need, I solved the problem by following Andrew Allen's advice of setting the attributes via the html template.